# Extracting min and max coordinates from MULTIPOLYGON into separate columns

Tags: r, dplyr, coordinates, polygon, r-sf

I have a large dataframe with a column called geometry.

```
> class(df$geometry)
```

> [1] "sfc_MULTIPOLYGON" "sfc"

The column looks like this:

```
head(df$geometry)
Geometry set for 6 features 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -157.9813 ymin: 56.73044 xmax: -152.267 ymax: 58.93569
epsg (SRID):    4269
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOLYGON (((-157.973 56.74355, -157.9727 56...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-157.5293 57.61359, -157.5293 5...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-152.268 57.62401, -152.2674 57...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-157.5457 58.86262, -157.5449 5...
MULTIPOLYGON (((-156.3857 58.88877, -156.3849 5...
```

I know I can access the numeric vector of latitude, for example, by digging down into the lists of lists, i.e.:

```
head(df$geometry[[1]][[1]][[1]][,1])
[1] -157.9730 -157.9727 -157.9721 -157.9716 -157.9708 -157.9707
```

I simply want to extract the min and max lat and lon for each row, and make each a column (so adding four columns to the data frame: lat_min, lat_max, lon_min, lon_max).

I have tried a number of options - including combinations of st_coordinates(), st_bbox(),unlist, but cannot seem to get this mapped over all rows . Please help.

packages: dpylr,tidyverse,tidyr,sf

Comment: Have a look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351620/creating-multiple-polygons-from-a-list-of-coordinate-matrices-using-sf-in-r/351644#351644 to get `bbox_list` in the reprex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a `reprex` of my comment:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

myshape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))[1:6,"NAME"]
head(myshape,3)
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23388 xmax: -80.43531 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
#>        NAME                       geometry
#> 1      Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
#> 2 Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
#> 3     Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...

#Extract coordinates
bbox_list <- lapply(st_geometry(myshape), st_bbox)

#To df
maxmin <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(bbox_list),nrow=nrow(myshape)))

#get names
names(maxmin) <- names(bbox_list[[1]])

#Final shape
myshape2=bind_cols(myshape,maxmin)
head(myshape2,3)
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 5 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -81.74107 ymin: 36.23388 xmax: -80.43531 ymax: 36.58965
#> epsg (SRID):    4267
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
#>        NAME                       geometry      xmin      ymin      xmax
#> 1      Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3... -81.74107 -80.90344 -76.33025
#> 2 Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...  36.23436  36.57286  36.07282
#> 3     Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3... -81.23989 -80.96577 -75.77316
#>        ymax
#> 1 -77.07531
#> 2  36.55629
#> 3 -77.21767
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: One note for R > 4.0: The matrix function must have the by row = T argument, if not strange things happen.